# Problema: Login php password_verify

Tags: php, login

tengo un problemas con un login que estoy haciendo.
El problema que tengo es que $pwdCheck == false siempre, aun que el usuario y la password concuerden con la que tengo en la base de datos

**--------------------------------/ Contexto /---------------------------------**

```
$pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['Password']);
 if ($pwdCheck == false) {
  header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
  exit();       
 }
 else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user_Id'] = $row['Id_user'];
  $_SESSION['user_Username'] = $row['Username'];

  header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
  exit();       
}
```

**--------------------------/ Comentarios adicionales /-------------------**

> En la base de datos Password es un longtext
>
> Estoy usando php 7.2.5
>
> Todo funciona correctamente a excepción de esa parte del login

Comment: Saludos! Has comprobado lo que trae `$password` y `$row['Password]` ? Puedes comprarlo por ejemplo utilizando `var_dump($password)` para saber el contenido de la variable.

Comment: array(4) {
  ["Id_user"]=>
  int(8)
  ["Username"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["Email"]=>
  string(16) "correo@gmail.com"
  ["Password"]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$iBV4sWm/iqaOKnKMfHalreAZ3REou8UlxtFtkSbr.vSXMPFteF63e"
}

Comment: Vale por lo que veo, has echo un `var_dump($row)` y de entre todos los datos, vemos que `$row['Password'`] es *$2y$10$iBV4sWm/iqaOKnKMfHalreAZ3REou8UlxtFtkSbr.vSXMPFteF63e* Ahora comprueba que contiene `$password` para saber por que la comparación entre ambas siempre es false.

Comment: Me da a mi que no estas encriptando `$password` para hacer la prueba y estas comparando texto plano con la encriptada.

Comment: @MarioGuiber  string(9) "prueba123"  que es la contraseña que escribí cuando cree la cuenta y use hash

Comment: @JDev a lo que vi en la documentación de la pagina oficial de php se debe de usar texto plano y extraer la contraseña de la base de datos y comparar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación de php, [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) el primer argumento es el texto plano y el segundo el cifrado mediante la función [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

Revisa que estés introduciendo el texto plano en el primer argumento de password_verify

```
<?php
    $password = "secret";
    $hash = \password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if (\password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
    } else {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hola, hice un echo var_dump($password); y este fue el resultado string(9) "prueba123"

Comment: @jahziel haz un password_hash de prueba123 y lo insertas en base de datos y después vuelves a comprobar

Comment: ya tengo el password_hash en la pagina de crear la cuenta pero el problema es en el login, cuando intento comparar la contraseña que ingresan en el input y la que tengo en la base de datos

Comment: Obvia la parte del login. Crea un hash con la contraseña y la pruebas directamente en código. Si te funciona, guarda el hash manualmente en la base de datos y vuelves a probar. Asegúrate que cuando generas el hash lo generas con PASSWORD_DEFAULT. Si sigues atascado pega el código dónde estás generando y almacenando el hash

Comment: efectivamente cuando guardo el hash manualmente funciona correctamente, como puedo arreglar eso?

Comment: Pega el código que tienes para insertar en base de datos a ver si podemos ayudarte

Comment: muchas gracias por todo, ya encontré el error y lo corregí